# How can I map all black pixels in a greyscale image to alpha so that it looks the same over a black background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I have a grayscale image, and I want to make all the black pixels transparent, keep all the white pixels the same, and make all the grey pixels partially transparent based on how dark they are. In other words, I want to get rid of all the black in this image, but I want it so it looks exactly the same as it did before when it’s on top of a black background. I’ve looked online I found info about how to do this with a layer mask, and it seemed pretty straightforward, but every time I try to do it the result is darker than the original and I’m not sure why. I want it to look exactly the same over a black background as it does now. Can anyone advise me here?

Edit: My question was marked as duplicate, but no matter how much I try the exact instructions in other answers, the result is slightly darker than the original.

Edit 2: I’m going to explain exactly what I’m trying. I have the layer I’m trying to remove black from. It has a transparent background, so I have it in front of a black background layer. I select the entire image and copy merged while only that layer and the black background are visible. Then I create a completely white layer that I put under the layer I want to remover Black from and in front of the white background. I add a layer mask to the new white layer. I go to channels, deselect all and select the mask channel. I paste the image I copied. Then I make the original layer I wanted to remove black from invisible. At this point, I can see the masked white layer in front of the black background, and it looks almost exactly how it should, but slightly darker. When I toggle the visibility of the original layer, it’s clearly slightly brighter. What gives?

The image was not in grayscale mode, but it was truly grayscale. As in, going to image -> adjustments -> black and white, and moving the sliders changes nothing.

Edit3: a play-by-play of what I am trying and the result:

[See screen shots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCUpb.jpg)

Comment: Fill the layar black after yove made it into a a mask.

Comment: I see 3 things that you could be doing wrong: 1. Your document is not grayscale but RGB (the mask is grayscale, so there can be a conversion issue). 2. You forget to hide the original image. 3. You have chosen the wrong color for the solid color.

Comment: I’m trying but it’s the same. Just added another edit.

Comment: I think this is still a duplicate unless you can show some sample images as to why it's not a duplicate. Each image is different and introducing transparency where there previously was none is going to make darks *appear* to be a bit lighter. Its a difference in *perception* due to opacity, not a color change. And certainly not a color change in a greyscale image.

Comment: I've added screenshots of the process.

Comment: Yeah I'd say it's darker because edge pixels are transparent now, at least partially.... so the black shows through. If you want it lighter you need to adjust the contrast of the mask to retain more white. Still, the method is a duplicate. Individual images will *always* require some specific alterations based upon their content and end use.

Comment: Is there no way to keep it exactly the same? I already adjusted the contrast how I wanted it when I made the grayscale image. I just don’t understand why it wouldn’t be possible to map black to 100% transparent and white to 100% opacity without some kind of change occurring. It seems like straight forward math to me. Either way, the method provided by the answer in the other question isn’t sufficient to solve my problem so either this question is not duplicate or that answer is flawed.

Comment: Anti-aliasing... when you have black against white, anti-aliasing creates opaque grey pixels. When you have black against transparency, anti-aliasing creates semi-transparent grey pixels. Put those semi-transparent pixels over black and they disappear (because black is darker). By increasing the contrast of the mask you can decrease the amount of transparency in those semi-transparent grey pixels, but you also run the risk of introducing a visual "halo" due to lighter edge pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the layer to lighten or screen and put the color on a layer behind it. Unless you need the parts to actually be transparent in order to save it for instance to web use.

Comment: What I need is to eventually overlap different versions of the same transparent layer, one for each color channel.

Comment: My question was marked as duplicate, but no matter how much I try the exact instructions in other answers, the result is slightly darker than the original.